# python saying no module but module exists

Tags: python, pip

Everytime I try to run my code, I get this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\underunder\OneDrive\Desktop\veinbot\bot.py", line 12, in <module> from pretty_help import DefaultMenu, PrettyHelp ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pretty_help'`

But when I do install the package, it says its already installed:

`Requirement already satisfied: discord-pretty-help in c:\users\underunder\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (1.3.3)`

I've tried to get this to work but nothing is working for some reason, please give me some advice, thank you.

Comment: The usual cause of this error is that you have multiple versions of Python.  If you do `python3 bot.py`, does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Basic Check**

You have a `pip` path or `python` interpreter path issue. Do the following steps,

1. Stick to using either `python` or `python3`
2. `python -m pip install <your_package_name>`

If you are using terminal to install and IDE's like Pycharm to work, kindly please update more details in the question to help you.

Recommendation: Thoroughly examine where you are installing your pip packages and which Python interpreter you are using.

**New Update:** Thank you for the updates.

Try the following

```
import pretty_help
from pretty_help import DefaultMenu
from pretty_help import PrettyHelp
```

- If your code breaks at `import pretty_help`, then you have not properly installed the packages
- `PrettyHelp` & `DefaultMenu` are submodules of `pretty_help` module. If your code breaks at `from pretty_help import ...`, then it means that you are using old code samples as reference.

Comment: I use Sublime Text Editor for the coding and then run in Windows Powershell.

Comment: @underunder - I added some more tips, please check and reply if any issues still happen.